# Testing an HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing

I got my first HTML helper to work, very exciting.
It is working and inserting HTML into a VIEW, so I have managed to learn that much. However, the HTML is not perfect.

I would like to create unit tests to verify the output of the helper. 
I have created a new test project , the code for the single test follows

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
Imports mvcUtils
Imports mvcUtils.Helpers

<TestClass()> Public Class testBoundField
    Inherits baseTestClass

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub FormRowHelper_test()

        Dim html1 As String = Html.FormRowHelper("controlId")

        Assert.AreEqual("perfect html", html1)

    End Sub

End Class
```

The mvcUtils.Helpers is the namespace where we find the helper.
I have dumbed down the HELPER call to focus on the issue. Again, it is working in the MVC project.

There error I am getting is

```
'FormRowHelper' is not a member of Html
```

I think I am missing an include. But I am having troubles seeing it. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what that is doing inside your test is trying to map to an HTML namespace, not the helper.  In your test, you have to construct the HtmlHelper class:

```
Dim helper As New HtmlHelper([params])
helper.FormRowHelper("controlId")
```

I don't know what it takes to construct the helper class; you may have to mock the instances of the classes it wants (with TypeMock or Moq or something else).

Comment: bummer. one of the main reasons we are moving to MVVM is that its supposedly easier to test.  I guess ill refactor so the helper just returns the string from a class. Do appreciate the input.